# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2+1} $

Tags: calculus, limits

I am struggling to figure out $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2+1} .$$ I've tried manipulating the inside of the square root but I cannot seem to figure out a simplification that helps me find the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $$y = \sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1}$$ then $$\ln y = \dfrac{\ln(n^2 + 1)}{n} = \dfrac{\ln n^2}{n} + \cdots = \dfrac{2 \ln n} n + \cdots  \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.$$  therefore 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} y = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1} = 1$$

Comment: This explanation makes sense to me except for where ln(n^2+1)/n = 2ln(n)/n + ... -> 0. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: there are two approximations there: (a) $\ln(n^2 + 1) = \ln(n^2) + \cdots = 2 \ln n+  \cdots$ (b) $\frac{\ln n}n = 0$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: Why are we allowed to make these approximations? Won't the other numbers ( + ... ) matter for our limit?

Comment: Just use $\log(n^2 + 1) \leq \log(n^3)$ for $n > 2$.

Comment: you can neglect $1$ in $n^2+1$. or you can use the fact $ln(n^2 + 1) = \ln(n^2(1 + 1/n^2) = \ln n^2 + \ln (1 + 1/n^2) = 2\ln n + 1/n^2 + \cdots$

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n = \sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1}$. Then $$n^{2/n} < a_n < (n + 1)^{2/n}.$$

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n} = 1$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} (n + 1)^{1/n} = 1$, it follows that the left- and right-most sides of the above inequality tend to $1$ as $n\to \infty$. Therefore, by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sqrt[n]{n^2+1} = (n^2+1)^{1/n} = e^{\frac{\ln(n^2+1)}{n}}.$$