# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I had a question regarding a proof for my analysis class

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2 + 1}$$

I've tried a handful of things, but in all cases, I have either reached a point that has no logical connection to the result, or I don't know how to prove a step.

I'm not asking for the answer, but advice on how I should proceed with this problem would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171150/find-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtnn21)

Comment: Do you know how to approach any similar limits? For instance, what $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is? Have you tried looking at this numerically (e.g. computing a few terms)? Can you, for instance, figure out whether the limit is above/below $2$?

Comment: My apologies. I apparently, did not search carefully enough. Thank you!